# Swift iOS -How to get tabBar height inside app delegate or a cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uicollectionviewcell, appdelegate

I know how to get the height of a tabBar inside a view controller:

```
// 49 points
tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.height
```

How would I get it inside `AppDelegate` or even a `UICollectionViewCell`?

Comment: Why do you need this value from a cell or the app delegate? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I created a Swift file, it's a class with just a UIKit and of type NSObject. I was trying to access it there because I'm using it to set a frame above the tabBar - some spacing. After I realized I couldn't access it there I said to myself let me see if I can find it in AppDelegate or a cell and I couldn't access it in ether of those places. I subclassed the tabBarController and still couldn't get it there. For now I just subtracted 49 and set the frame for the file and it works fine but if tabBar size ever changes I'll be sol.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can use AutoLayout for this (inside view controller where you access tabbar's height). Probably even in Interface Builder if you use storyboards.

Comment: app is 100% programmatic

Comment: The only way than i know to get what you want is to create the view controller  inside your AppDelegate by using storyboard.instantiateViewController, then you can get the height for your tabBar.

Comment: that's still getting it from the view controller. It looks like it cannot get done. Thanks anyway!